# merging 2 files based on one field using AWK

Tags: awk

I have 2 text files like these:

file1:

```
chr1    90478700    90478750    57  chr1    90478684    90478796    ZNF326  ENST00000340281.4   annotated
chr15   91043226    91043250    1456    chr15   91043226    91043337    IQGAP1  ENST00000268182.5   annotated
chr15   91425050    91425100    107 chr15   91424515    91425105    FURIN   ENST00000268171.3   annotated
```

file2:

```
chr16   84651500    84651520    1192    chr16   84651443    84651520    COTL1   ENST00000262428.4   annotated
chr12   85285700    85285750    928 chr12   85285610    85285899    ZNF326  ENST00000266682.5   annotated
chr16   85822600    85822650    155 chr16   85822579    85822656    FURIN   ENST00000253457.3   annotated
```

I want to merge these 2 files based on the 8th column.
The result would have all columns from the 1st file and the 2nd file.
In fact the resulting file would have 20 tab separated columns.

I am trying to do that using the following command in `AWK` but it does not return the expected output:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$8] = 1; next} $8 in a' file1 file2 > results.txt
```

do you know how to fix it?

expected output:

```
chr1    90478700    90478750    57  chr1    90478684    90478796    ZNF326  ENST00000340281.4   annotated   chr12   85285700    85285750    928 chr12   85285610    85285899    ZNF326  ENST00000266682.5   annotated
chr15   91425050    91425100    107 chr15   91424515    91425105    FURIN   ENST00000268171.3   annotated   chr16   85822600    85822650    155 chr16   85822579    85822656    FURIN   ENST00000253457.3   annotated
```

Comment: reformat your `file1` content, it looks like a single line now

Comment: Your expected output seems to be inconsistent with your provided input. It is thus hard to understand what you would like to obtain. Which file has precedence?

Answer (score 1):

Base on your description and your data, this will do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}NR==FNR{a[$8]=$0;next}$8 in a{print a[$8],$0}' file1 file2 > results.txt
```

Output / results.txt:

```
chr1    90478700    90478750    57  chr1    90478684    90478796    ZNF326  ENST00000340281.4   annotated   chr12   85285700    85285750    928 chr12   85285610    85285899    ZNF326  ENST00000266682.5   annotated
chr15   91425050    91425100    107 chr15   91424515    91425105    FURIN   ENST00000268171.3   annotated   chr16   85822600    85822650    155 chr16   85822579    85822656    FURIN   ENST00000253457.3   annotated
```

My answer actually is not far from your own attempt.
You have to save file1 to the hash `a`, use $8 as the key.
And in file2 you have to print contents from file1 first and then file2's own.

Note if file1 could be empty, you should change `NR==FNR` to different file checking methods, like `ARGIND==1` for GNU awk, or `FILENAME=="file2"` etc.